Issue while importing clifford lib from ipython (numba issue?)
Importing clifford fails from ipython as follow:
$ ipython
Python 3.11.7 (main, Dec 15 2023, 18:12:31) [GCC 11.2.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import clifford as cf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import clifford as cf

File /mnt/stockage/Anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/clifford/__init__.py:95
     92 from clifford.io import write_ga_file, read_ga_file  # noqa: F401
     94 from ._version import __version__  # noqa: F401
---> 95 from . import _numba_utils
     97 from ._settings import pretty, ugly, eps, print_precision  # noqa: F401
     98 import clifford.taylor_expansions as taylor_expansions

File /mnt/stockage/Anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/clifford/_numba_utils.py:85
     83 if not DISABLE_JIT:
     84     njit = numba.njit
---> 85     generated_jit = numba.generated_jit
     86 else:
     87     def njit(f=None, **kwargs):

AttributeError: module 'numba' has no attribute 'generated_jit'

In [2]: import numba

In [3]: numba.__version__
Out[3]: '0.59.1'

The last version of numba seems to be installed. I could switch to the usage of the kingdon library, but how to fix this issue?
Thanks

generated_jit was deprecated and removed in numba 0.59, so you need to install an older version
